# Making API Call continuously even when the Android application is closed - RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I have developed an android application where I need to fetch a list using rest API call and show on my application. The list gets updated frequently. I have written the following code using RxAndroid and retrofit to make the api call :

```
private void fetchAllData() {
        disposable.add(Observable.interval(0,60,TimeUnit.SECONDS).
                subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
                flatMap(i -> apiService.getData(fetchActiveData)).
                observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
                subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<DataResponse>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onNext(DataResponse dataResponse) {
                       Log.i(TAG, "The rest api was called again");
                       List<Data> dataList = dataResponse.getData();
                       displayData(dataList,false);
                   }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "The exception is thrown :: " + e.getMessage());
                        displayData(null,true);
                        fetchAllData();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                })
        );
    }
```

Using above code , I am able to make api call every 60 seconds and update my list. If there is any new item which I am not displaying on the application , then for that i have the logic to show the notification.

To enhance my application , I need to make the api call when the application is closed and not running on background. Can someone please suggest me how do I achieve this with RxJava.

Comment: You can not do this when there is no process running when app get killed. Try using `JobShedular` . But every 60 seconds you simply can't do this in background unless you are using a foreground service .

Comment: If you don't want the service to be called in the background then you can dispose of the object when you app activity is finished.

Comment: Since your application is not in foreground, user will not be able to see the data you are trying to fetch from cloud. So it doesn't make sense of you trying to download data when app is in background or not running. What you can do is whenever the app is launched, just do a API call first and fetch all the data you need and then keep running the timer you have already created.

Comment: My requirement is even if the app is not in foreground , if there is any change is the data set , the user should be notified. Suppose if we stop some messaging application , then if there is a new message we do get the notification.